# getElementById variable scope

Tags: javascript, scope, getelementbyid

on the following example, why isn't 'status.value' accessible from inside the function? 
If I replace 'status.value' by document.getElementById("Label").value inside the function all works well.
Thanks.

```
<html>
<body onload="Ticker()">
 <label>Connection Status:</label>
 <input type="text" readonly="true" value="Idle" id="Label">
 <input type="button" value="Start/Stop" onclick="run=!run">
 <br>

 <script>
 var status = document.getElementById("Label");
 var run;

  function Ticker() {
      setTimeout( Ticker, 100 );

        if(run){
           status.value = "Connected";
        }else{
           status.value = "Disconnected";
        }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is accessible, what's actually your problem? Please post a runnable snippet that reproduces your error and tell us what you actually expect.

Comment: Where are you calling your `Ticker()` function?

Comment: sorry about that. edited

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

  <body onload="Ticker()">
    <label>Connection Status:</label>
    <input type="text" readonly="true" value="Idle" id="Label">
    <input type="button" value="Start/Stop" onclick="run=!run">
    <br>

    <script>
      var run;

      function Ticker() {
        setTimeout(Ticker, 100);
        var status = document.getElementById("Label");
        if (run) {
          status.value = "Connected";
        } else {
          status.value = "Disconnected";
        }
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but I don't want to go around the issue. I want to understand it..

Comment: Ok, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Since the function under timer execute in the next event cycle, it wont be knowing abour the status. If you want to pass the 'status' you should pass it as parameter to the settimeout function as below:-

```
 var status = document.getElementById("Label");
function Ticker(status) {
        setTimeout(Ticker, 100,status);      
        if (run) {
          status.value = "Connected";
        } else {
          status.value = "Disconnected";
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to work. Also, doesn't make much sense to me, since it is a global variable. Wouldn't variable 'run' have the same issue?

Comment: yes, sorry forgot to mention this. You can pass variable run to the Ticker same way.